# What exactly were the DJ Condor segments supposed to be?

Tags: oretachi-ni-tsubasa-wa-nai

After watching to the end of the anime of *Oretachi ni Tsubasa wa Nai*, I still don't entirely understand the DJ Condor segments. They seemed to be some sort of radio narration of the story, but also had a great deal of stuff that was clearly not actually occurring. The end-of-episode previews were mostly stuff from the next episode, but the segments at the beginning of the episodes seemed usually disjoint from the story and random. They're mostly inconsistent with the story as they involve characters interacting who have never actually met (as far as I could tell).

Is there some reasonable canonical interpretation for what these segments are supposed to mean (either based on the anime or the VN), or are the just totally random? Does it have to do with

> Youji hiding in the abyss of his own mind?

[image]